# Is there a workaround for the lack of type class backtracking?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

In [this talk around the 1:20 mark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=hIZxTQP1ifo#t=4830), Edward Kmett mentions the lack of "type class backtracking" in Haskell. Consider the problem of "set equality" (where order and multiplicity are disregarded) implemented on lists:

```
equals :: [a] -> [a] -> Bool
```

By the nature of type classes I cannot provide an inefficient O(n²) comparison if all we have is `Eq a` but efficiently compare the lists in O(n log n) if we have `Ord a`.

I did understand why such a facility would be problematic. At the same time, Edward says that there are "tricks you could play" mentioning for instance type families.

Hence my question is, what would be a workaround to achieve the same effect:

- an (inefficient) default implementation is provided
- if the user can provide some additional information about the type, we "unlock" a more efficient implementation

This workaround does not necessarily need to use type classes.

**Edit**: Some people suggested simply providing `equals` and `efficientEquals` as two distinct methods. In general I agree that this is the more Haskell-idiomatic approach. However, I am not convinced that this is always possible. For instance, what if the equals method above is itself part of a type class:

```
class SetLike s where
    equals :: Eq a => s a -> s a -> Bool
```

Assume that this class has been provided by someone else so I cannot simply add a new function to the typeclass. I now want to define the instance for `[]`. I know that `[]` can always provide an implementation of `equals` no matter what constraints there are on `a` but I cannot tell my instance to use the more efficient version if more information about `a` is available.

Maybe I could wrap the list in a newtype and tag it with some additional type information?

Comment: This is quite interesting and I don't know the answer to this. But a quick and dirty solution would be to define a different function like `efficientEquals :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool` and `equals :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool`.

Comment: Please make it clear that we are talking about comparing lists _disregarding order_ (and possibly multiplicity as well). Clearly `(==)` does not require O(n^2) on lists.

Comment: IIRC, GHC allows one to specify a `{-# RULE ... equals = efficientOrdEquals #-}` which gets applied only if the RHS type-checks. In this way, calls that are statically known to involve ordered types would get the efficient version.

Comment: @chi, I believe that ends up being very finicky. The rules don't run until simplification, when the type checker has gone away and taken all its instance info with it (something I'd like it to stop doing for a different reason, as it happens, but I'm not guru enough to attempt it). This means the instance info is only available in the presence of a constraint, and only if that constraint has not been specialized away. So it's very easy to have something that's `Ord`, but that the simplifier doesn't *know* is `Ord`.

Comment: There are some techniques using `OverlappingInstances`, or closed type families that can be used to get something like what you're looking for in some cases (though not really here; unless you're okay with, say, enumerating/duplicating all types with `Ord` instances you care about). See [the "advanced overlap"](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/AdvancedOverlap) wiki page. The ["extra method trick"](http://brandon.si/code/how-the-haskell-prelude-avoids-overlapping-types-in-show/) might also be relevant here.

Comment: "if the user can provide some additional information about the type" - what are you thinking of here? I can think of lots of solutions that would seem to satisfy the workaround you're looking for as stated, but they're kind of trivial and I think you'd agree they're equivalent but worse than just having two functions like Jeffrey suggests

Comment: The main problem here is that Eq is a superclass of Ord. So *every* Ord type is also an Eq type, which means you want your Eq case to be selected only for cases where there `Ord a` does *not* hold. The type class system in Haskell is strongly designed to make sure it never commits to the negative of a constraint; this property is at the heart of a lot of the consistency guarantees it provides, because with separate compilation of modules GHC can never tell the difference between "no instance exists" and "no instance is in scope".

Comment: I can think of ways you could come up with an `equals` that works with both Eq and Ord instances, but I can't think of any way that wouldn't just complain about ambiguous type variables when called on things are instances of Ord. You'd end up having to manually say `(equals :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool) xs ys` at every call site. And if you're willing to manually declare which version of equals you want to call, they might as well have different names so it's easier to do so.

Comment: I edited the question to address some of the points raised in the comments. I hope I did not deviate too much from the original formulation.  In general I agree that providing two distinct methods is the more idiomatic way. However, I am not convinced that is always an option (see edit).

Comment: Ah, I see. I think that actually needs quite a different solution than we've been aiming for. The `equals` from `SetLike` is required to be polymorphic in `Eq a`, only switching between implementations on `s`. So I think even if you managed a type class overloaded function that switched on whether there was an Ord constant or not, doing `instance SetLike [] where equals = ordOrEqEquals` would just select the slow Eq version out of the overload! But if you're willing to use a different data structure than plain lists, then jberryman has shown how you can use GADTs to address this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the scenario from your edit, you could use a `GADT` as proof of your `Ord` constraint:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

import Data.List

class SetLike s where
    equals :: Eq a => s a -> s a -> Bool

data OrdList a where
    OrdList :: Ord a=> [a] -> OrdList a

instance SetLike OrdList where
    equals (OrdList a) (OrdList b) = sort a == sort b
```

And for fun here's something that uses makes use of the `OverlappingInstances` trick I mention in my comment. There are lots of ways to do this sort of thing:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures, OverlappingInstances, UndecidableInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances #-}

import Data.List

class Equals a where
    equals :: [a] -> [a] -> Bool

    default equals :: Ord a=> [a] -> [a] -> Bool
    equals as bs = sort as == sort bs

instance Equals Int
instance Equals Integer
instance Equals Char
-- etc.

instance (Eq a)=> Equals a where
    equals = error "slow version"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, OverlappingInstances does away with some of the guarantees we usually get with typeclasses, doesn't it? I really like the GADT solution, though!